# Alter default privileges in postgres for other roles

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role

Let's say I have a role called `user1`, `user2` and `postgres`.

Is it possible to alter the default privileges while logged in as `postgres` for objects created by `user1` so that `user2` can see them?

This is what I currently have, but this only works if I'm logged in as `user1`:

```
alter default privileges grant usage on schemas to user2;
alter default privileges grant select on tables to user2;
alter default privileges grant usage, select on sequences to user2;
```

Is it possible to get this to work while logged in as `postgres`?

Answer (score 1):

To add default privileges for a different user, use the `FOR ROLE` clause:

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE user1 ...`

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) for details.

As to the required permissions to run that statement, the documentation says:

> You can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of.

That means that, unless you are a superuser, you can only use roles in `FOR ROLE` of which you are directly or indirectly a member.